# DXA 2.2 - JAVA Unable to use Jackson default naming strategy, it always applies UpperCamelCase naming strategy on request and response

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, dxa2.2

I am using dxa-2.2 java, there is rest controller which takes some request and return response.

After investigation i found DxaSpringInitialization.class on dxa framework initializing objectMapper with UpperCamelCase Strategy,

```
objectMapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(new UpperCamelCaseStrategy());
```

And since DxaSpringInitialization is being imported on App (@SpringBootApplication) like @Import({DxaSpringInitialization.class}),

Naming strategy is being applied to controller request and response.

could someone please suggest how could i use default naming strategy on specific controller